# How to set element's width equal to half of the window's width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to automatically generate rounded values with the floor function but it stays static. Can you please help me how to improve my code ? Thank you very much.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    width_split = $(document).width();
    width_split = Math.floor(width_split / 2);

    $(document).resize(function() {
        width_split = $(document).width();
        width_split = Math.floor(width_split / 2);  
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<p style="position:absolute; right:"+width_split+"px;">
   .content
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `right` value inside your JS not in the HTML DOM

Try:

HTML:

```
<p id="mypar" style="position:absolute;">
   .content
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  width_split = $(document).width();
  width_split = Math.floor(width_split / 2);
$(document).resize(function(){
  width_split = $(document).width();
  width_split = Math.floor(width_split / 2);  
  $('#mypar').css("right", width_split+'px');//ADD THIS
});

$('#mypar').css("right", width_split+'px');//ADD THIS
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7KWa5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `width_split` for `<p>` tag  by jquery, the way you are appying `width_split` at inline `p` tag is wrong. Something like should be

**Html**

```
   <p id="para" style="position:absolute"; >
       .content
    </p>
```

**js**

```
$("#para").css("right", width_split + "px");
```

instead of

```
<p style="position:absolute; right:"+width_split+"px;">
///--------------------------this is wrong---^
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also update HTML tag

```
$('pID').css('right', width_split.toString()+'px');
```

Inside the document.resize function.

Answer (score 0):

#### The simpler solution

Select each element you wish to adjust and apply the style directly

```
$('.your-selector').css({theProperty: halfWidth});
```

But this way you have to modify the js for every new element that you add to the html.

### An generic approach would be

Put a marker (MRK) class on "reactive" objects, and include in the marker also the css property you want to set to be width/2 (eg. MRK-left, or MRK-margin-left)

Then on window resize, search for the elements that contain the marker, extract the css property, and set it on them.

## [DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/albertmatyi/y2WRw/)

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var halfWidth = $(window).width() / 2;
    $('*[class*=MRK-]').each(function(){  // selects all elements having a class  
       var cls = $(this).attr('class')   // property that contains MRK
       var cssPropName = /MRK-([\w-]+)/.exec(cls)[1]; // extracts the info MRK
       var css = {};
       css[cssPropName] = halfWidth;  // creates the styleobject with the info
       $(this).css(css);
    });
});
```

In html you would write:

```
<div class="MRK-left"></div>
```

or

```
<p class="MRK-margin-left"></p>
```

The result at 800px width would be:

```
<div class="MRK-left" style="left: 400px"></div>
```

or

```
<p class="MRK-margin-left" style="margin-left: 400px"></div>
```

And you can change like this any property without changing the js logic

Comment: What sorcery is this ?

Comment: Added idea explanation and provided fiddle